# Variables in Babel evaluation with SQL blocks

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, sql-interactive-mode

According to the org-mode manual, you can set variables in code blocks
as follows:

```
#+HEADERS: :var foo="blah"
#+BEGIN_SRC elisp
(message foo)
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: blah
```

However, when I try to do this with a babel block with SQL, I have no
good luck:

```
#+HEADERS: :var foo="blah"
#+BEGIN_SRC sql
SELECT foo
#+END_SRC
```

I get the predictable error:

```
Error: No such column: foo
```

The output I'd like to see is something like:

```
blah
```

In the `*SQL*` buffer. I've spent a lot of time trying to figure it
out but I haven't made any progress yet.

So is what I'm trying to do possible with SQL?

Thanks!

Edit: based on the comments below, the following does work after I explicitly load ob-sqlite:

```
#+HEADERS: :var foo="blah"
#+BEGIN_SRC sqlite :db ":memory:"
SELECT "$foo";
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: blah
```

The problem is that I have a connection in the *SQL* buffer that I want to reuse rather than hard-code the path to the database via :db since I am executing the same query on multiple databases.

Almost there!

Edit 2: In the end, I ended up doing this:

```
#+HEADERS: :var foo="blah"
#+HEADERS: :var bar="boop"
#+BEGIN_SRC sqlite :header yes :db (some-lisp-call-here)
SELECT $foo, $bar;
#END_SRC
```

I can live with this but I went further and factored out the common parameters

```
# -*- org -*-
#+PROPERTY: header-args:sqlite :header yes :db (some-lisp-call-here) :var foo="blah" :var bar="boop"
```

Comment: Try `SELECT $foo` instead. (I cannot test this myself right now, but this is what reading the relevant part of `ob-sql.el` tells me *should* work.)

Comment: Should have mentioned that I tried this as well. It doesn't fail, but has no output.

Comment: If you look at [`org-babel-execute:sql`](http://orgmode.org/cgit.cgi/org-mode.git/tree/lisp/ob-sql.el?id=release_8.2.10#n90) you can see that the only way of communicating with a database it supports is via `org-babel-eval`, i.e. by creating a shell command, executing it, and processing the output. As far as I can it *cannot* pass commands to an `*SQL*` buffer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
#+begin_src sql :engine postgresql :cmdline "-U wvxvw -W secret -d personal"
select * from phonebook;
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
| name |          phone |
|------+----------------|
| Dad  | XXX-XX-XXXXXXX |
| Mom  | YYY-YY-YYYYYYY |

#+header: :var pn="phone"
#+begin_src sql :engine postgresql :cmdline "-U wvxvw -W secret -d personal"
select $pn from phonebook;
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
|          phone |
|----------------|
| XXX-XX-XXXXXXX |
| YYY-YY-YYYYYYY |
```

To confirm what Constantine said. This should work (and it works for me).
What can possibly fail? - spelling, wrong user (not the one that owns the database), empty table and so on.

To make sure the block expanded as you'd expect: <kbd>M-x</kbd>`org-babel-expand-src-block`. Or you could open `ob-sql.el` and instrument some of the functions that you believe should process the data for debugging, so that you could see the intermediate state.

Comment: I updated the question with what I've tried as well as what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: @nonchalant I don't think that at this time Babel supports `:session` for `sql`, so it looks like that if you want to use that, or another process, which already communicates with a database, then you'll have to implement it yourself... or maybe someone else will do it sooner :)

Comment: Ok, I found something I can live with for now.